# ¿Cómo implemento un constructor que inicialice el mes al valor recibido por parametro y los demas atributos a 0?

Tags: java

```
package prog_03;


public class Fecha {

    enum enumMes {

        mes;
        int dia;
        int anio;
    }
    Fecha (enumMes mes){
        
    }
    Fecha (int dia, enumMes mes, int anio){
    
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que me pide el ejercicio:

- Declara en el fichero de la clase un tipo enumerado, denominado enumMes, para los meses del año.
- La clase debe contener un atributo para el día, otro para mes (del tipo enumerado declarado) y un tercero para el año.
- Implementa un constructor que inicialice el mes al valor recibido por parámetro y los demás atributos a 0. Observa su cabecera en el siguiente código:
  Fecha (enumMes mes){

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? estoy un poco perdida

Comment: Te doy ideas. El constructor debe ser public, Hay que asignarle con this las variables que recibe el construtor. Las variables de la clase deberían ser private.

Comment: Necesitas declarar los doce meses dentro del enum. Y el constructor `Fecha(EnumMes m)` puede delegar en el otro constructor, llamándolo así: `Fecha(m,0,0);`